# Fiddler cannot get response from long running method

Tags: fiddler, asp.net-web-api, fiddlercore

I have used Fiddler to post manually to a method of my service for testing. And This is a long running method (taking several minutes).
But after my method return, Fiddler didn't show the response (just hyphen - in the Result column).
Please give me advices to troubleshoot this problem?
Thanks.
MillDol.

Comment: As asked in response to your post in the Fiddler discussion group, you should explain why you think the service is returning anything? Do you have a WireShark or NetMon trace?

Comment: Yes, my service is implemented by ASP.NET web api. So I can debug the service code by Visual Studio. I have incresead the request timeout and put "Connection:Keep-Alive" to HTTP request header, but It still didn't work. Is there any standard about the time to keep a HTTP connection opened. I've just known that we should not keep this resource for a long time. Thanks!